# postgresql, My query is too slow. What's the problem? (Takes more than 1 minute)

Tags: postgresql

Below is the query that I use.
I want to see the results within 2 or 3 seconds, but it takes more than a minute.

```
with meta as (
    select
        item_name
        , item_sp 
        , grade
    from
        meta_info
    where
        item_sp = 'Bc_1'
        and grade_no = (
            select
                max(grade_no)
            from
                meta_info
            where 
                item_sp = 'Bc_1'
        )
) select 
    *
from (
    select
        m.grade
        , i.item_sp
        , i.regist_date
        , i.serial_key
        , row_number() over(partition by i.serial_key order by m.grade) as serial_key_number
    from 
        item_info i, meta m
    where 
        i.item_sp = 'Bc_1'
        and i.regist_date = '20210314' 
        and i.regist = true
        and i.item_name = m.item_name
        and i.item_sp = m.item_sp
    ) i
where 
    not exists (select 
                    serial_key 
                from 
                    item_info ii
                where 
                    ii.item_sp = 'Bc_1'
                    and ii.regist_date < '20210314'  
                    and i.serial_key = ii.serial_key)
    and i.serial_key_number = 1;
```

The total number of tables used is meta_info and item_info.

meta_info contains the basic information of the product, and item_info is a table that stores the grade and serial key of each product by date.

In the item_info table, the serial key by product is not a key value, so it can be duplicated.

Here's the problem.
A query that compares all serial keys prior to a particular registration date to look up unregistered serial keys once, and extracts only the highest-rated serial key values because there are duplicates of the serial key values by grade.
But there are more than 10 million item_info data.

Below is the table structure.

```
1. meta_info
item_sp    grade    item_name    grade_no  
 ac_1        A         BOOK         2
 ac_1        B         FOOD         2
 bc_1        A         WATER        2
 cc_1        C         MOUSE        2
  .          .           .          .
  .          .           .          .
  .          .           .          .
```

```
2. item_info
item_no(key)    item_sp    item_name    serial_key      regist_date    regist 
   1              ac_1       BOOK       fgd5756ffdsf     20210314       true
   2              ac_1       FOOD        bnffdhtj        20210314       true     
   3              bc_1       WATER      fdfh4fsdfsf      20210314       true    
   4              cc_1       MOUSE      htt55434         20210314       true
   .               .           .           .                .            .
   .               .           .           .                .            .
   .               .           .           .                .            .
   .               .           .           .                .            .
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This took 13 seconds, which is quite a bit less than one minute.  Please show the plan as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the time is going to the last index scan in your plan.  You should be able to greatly improve it by adding an index `on item_info (serial_key, item_sp, regist_date)`

Comment: Thank you. It's my first time dealing with large data, so I don't know many things. Thank you for your answer.